# How to get the link of an element using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom, href

I want to get the url of an image from anime website, this is where the image url located.

```
<a href="/anime/strike-witches-3- 
 775962/episode-03-692659" 
 class="ka-url-wrapper video-item- 
 poster rounded"  cryptkey="
 8cefe99856a1e0da611
 782dd2909018757142
 568486877b1fd24ad7df4fa9cc1" 
 cryptiv="77a23d
 8ce0c90dc66559f3e610a2006a" 
 style="background:  
 url(&quot;https://
 www1.kickassanime.rs/
 uploads/026260.jpg&quot;) 
center center / cover no-repeat;">
<div class="video-item-badge 
rounded">SUB</div><div 
class="video-item-badge 
rounded">EP 03</div></a>
```

> style="background: url(" **https://
> www1.kickassanime.rs/uploads/026260.jpg**
> ") center center / cover no-repeat;">

I want to get only the bold text,
So I try this code

```
alert(
document.querySelectorAll(" 
[style*=background] ")[0]
.getAttribute('href'))
```

But the respose of the system is

```
  /anime/strike-witches-3- 
  775962/episode-03-692659
```

Please help me to get my desired url (bold letters)

Comment: There are no bold letters - I assume you want the background url?

Answer (score 1):

You're reading the href property which does not contain the image url.

You can extract the entire syle and then use some regex to extract the part inside `url(....)`

```js
var style = document.querySelector("[style*=background]").style.background;

var regex = /url\("(.*?)"\).*/
var url = regex.exec(style)[1]
console.log(url);
```

```html
<a href="/anime/strike-witches-3-775962/episode-03-692659" 
 class="ka-url-wrapper video-item-poster rounded"  
 cryptkey="8cefe99856a1e0da611782dd2909018757142568486877b1fd24ad7df4fa9cc1" 
 cryptiv="77a23d8ce0c90dc66559f3e610a2006a" 
 style="background: url(&quot;https://www1.kickassanime.rs/uploads/026260.jpg&quot;) center center / cover no-repeat;">
<div class="video-item-badge rounded">SUB</div>
<div class="video-item-badge rounded">EP 03</div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the DOM stye api to get the background image url.

> The `element.style` property lets you know the CSS properties that were defined as inline in that element (programmatically, or defined in the style attribute of the element).

Once you have the style of the element then you can get the background image url from the 'style.background' property and then you can use regex to extract the image url.

**Example:**

```js
 const elem = document.querySelectorAll("[style*=background]")[0];
 const bg = elem.style.background.replace(/url\("(.*?)"\).*/, "$1")
 console.log(bg)
```

```html
    <a href="/anime/strike-witches-3-775962/episode-03-692659" class="ka-url-wrapper video-item- poster rounded" cryptkey="  8cefe99856a1e0da611  782dd2909018757142  568486877b1fd24ad7df4fa9cc1" cryptiv="77a23d  8ce0c90dc66559f3e610a2006a" style="background:url(&quot;https://www1.kickassanime.rs/uploads/026260.jpg&quot;) center center / cover no-repeat;">
        <div class="video-item-badge 
       rounded">SUB</div>
        <div class="video-item-badge 
       rounded">EP 03</div>
    </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.querySelector(...).style.background.split('"')[1]
```